# does a drupal install overwrite my database? what about uninstall?

Tags: database, drupal

I'm storing a hefty database on a webserver currently. Strictly the database and literally nothing else on the site. I want to install drupal which requires it's own back end database. Will it share or allow me to point to a specific database, or rather delete my current tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal installer will ask you to nominate a database to install its schema to, as well as a username/password combo. I believe (although I may be wrong) that you need to manually create the database yourself before it will be able to install.